# Charset and collation priority in MySQL

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

In MySQL I can configure the charset and collation at both **Server**, **Database** and **Table** level.

*Is this the same level of priority? From the least to the most specific?*
I didn't manage to find it in the DOCS.

### e.g.:

#### SERVER level

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "char%";
```

RESULTS IN:

```
character_set_client        utf8
character_set_connection    utf8
character_set_database      latin1
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results       utf8
character_set_server        latin1
character_set_system        utf8
```

#### DB level

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA;
```

RESULTS IN:

```
name        character_set_name  collation_name
my_database latin1              latin1_swedish_ci
```

#### TABLE level

```
SELECT T.table_name, CCSA.character_set_name 
FROM information_schema.`TABLES` T,
     information_schema.`COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY` CCSA
WHERE CCSA.collation_name = T.table_collation
  AND T.table_schema = "my_database";
```

RESULTS IN:

```
table_name      character_set_name
my_table1           latin1
my_table2           utf8
```

Comment: You can define Collation at **Column** level too. I believe if there is a provision for such granularity, then they must be considering the definition done at the lowest level as a priority.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Database setting is the *default* when creating a table.
The Table setting is the *default* when creating a column.
The Column setting is the only thing that matters.

Well, that is not completely true.  You need to specify what encoding (`CHARACTER SET`) and collation is used by the *client*.  That's where `character_set_client/connection/results` comes into play.  Those 3 are normally set the same as each other, but they do not need to match the column's `CHARACTER SET`.

If the column does not match those settings, the MySQL will transcode the bytes on the fly as they go between client and server.  Note that this lets you have different charsets for different columns in the *same* table.

The previous paragraph says nothing about the Table and Database settings -- because they are irrelevant.  (Because they are only *defaults*.)  Once a table has been `CREATEd`, each column's charset has been 'set in stone'.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find the detail of the different levels (server,database, table and column) in this section of the manual [10.3 Specifying Character Sets and Collations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-syntax.html) and subsequent pages. At the database, table and column levels it states that the character set and collation from the previous level is used if you don't explicitly set it, which would equate to your notion of the least to the most specific.